# how to get numeric value from edit control

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Sorry if this is too trivial, but I can't figure out how to get numeric value entered into edit control. MFC edit control represented by [`CEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd866e2d-a811-4172-ac56-b72606bd3ea5%28v=vs.90%29) class.

Thank you.

Comment: Please mark [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10480367/1889329) as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Besides the `GetWindowText()` method already mentioned, you can also bind it via [Dialog Data Exchange (DDX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange) to an `integer`/`unsigned integer`/`double`/`float` value. The [`DDX_Text()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines#ddx_text) routine offers several overloads for numeric values that can be used like this:

```cpp
void CYourAwesomeDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_NUMBER, m_iNumber);
}
```

where `m_iNumber` is a member of your `CYourAwesomeDialog` class of a supported numeric type.

You have to call

```cpp
UpdateData(TRUE);
```

in order to write the values from the controls into the variables. Call

```cpp
UpdateData(FALSE);
```

to do it the other way around - from the variables in the controls.

EDIT (Bonus):

Upon re-reading my answer, I noticed that `UpdateData(...)` needs a `BOOL` variable - corrected. So I had an idea for people who like readability. Because I always got confused which call did which direction, you could introduce an enum to make it more readable, like so (maybe in stdafx.h or some central header):

```cpp
enum UpdateDataDirection
{
    FromVariablesToControls = FALSE,
    FromControlsToVariables = TRUE
}
```

and you would just have to write:

```cpp
UpdateData(FromVariablesToControls);
```

or

```cpp
UpdateData(FromControlsToVariables);
```

Comment: I like the suggestion about renaming true/false, as this is really totally confusing everytime. :)

Answer (score 10):

`CEdit` derives from `CWnd`, so it has a member function called [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db50wx7h(v=vs.100)) which you can call to get the text in the `CEdit`, and then convert that into numeric type, `int` or `double` - depending on what you expect user to enter:

```
CString text;
editControl.GetWindowText(text);

//here text should contain the numeric value
//all you need to do is to convert it into int/double/whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to need that functionality regularly, say on multiple dialogs, then you may as well subclass your own CEdit-derived class for doing the getting, setting and validation work.

```
class CFloatEdit : public CEdit
{
public:
    CFloatEdit();
    void SetValue(double v) {
        // format v into a string and pass to SetWindowText
        }
    double GetValue() {
        // validate and then return atoi of GetWindowText
        }
    void OnChar(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags) {
        // only allow digits, period and backspace
        }
};
```

Something like that, make sure the message map passes along all other messages to the parent CEdit. You could extend it to have customisable lower and upper limit and decimal places setting.

Comment: I would use DDV for validation work - but you can pass a pointer to this control to highlight validation errors

Comment: Considering CEdit already has a number mode (only allowing digits and decimal separator) it would make sense to have functions to get/set int/long/double values, instead of forcing every single developer on the earth to implement its own...

Comment: @mBardos This is another case of a user requesting what the framework [already does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10480367/1889329).